# labeling in barplot()

Tags: r

I am attempting to add names to the columns of my bar plot... There are 2 bars in each group that would share the same name..

I am using code like this:

```
l<-c(.6286, .2212, .9961, .5831, .8703, .6990, .9952, .9948)

r<-c(.2721, .5663, .0, .3961, .0696, .1180, .0, .0)

tab<-rbind(l,r)

plot<-barplot(tab, beside=TRUE, axisnames=FALSE, main = 'Time Spent Left vs. Right', sub = 'Female 2c', xlab= 'Days After Entry', ylab = 'Proportion of Time Spent', col=c('blue', 'red'), ylim = c(0,1))
legend('topleft', .8,  c('Left' , 'Right'), pch=c(.8), col=c('blue', 'red'))
names.arg = jd2c$d.in.p

names.arg=c(3,4,5,6,6,7,10,11) #listed for informational purposes, same as jd2c$d.in.p
```

jd2c$d.in.p is also listed above..   For some reason the names.arg function does not seem to be doing what I would expect. Even if I put it within the parenthesis of the bar plot() function..

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using your data and setting `names.arg` appropriately and `axisnames=TRUE`, I get a reasonable result.  I tweaked a couple of other things (set `las=1` to turn axis labels horizontal, used `fill` rather than `col` in the legend, got rid of `pch=0.8`).

```
par(las=1)
bnames <- c(3,4,5,6,6,7,10,11) #listed for informational purposes, same as jd2c$
plot<-barplot(tab, beside=TRUE, axisnames=TRUE,
              main = 'Time Spent Left vs. Right',
              sub = 'Female 2c', xlab= 'Days After Entry',
              ylab = 'Proportion of Time Spent',
              col=c('blue', 'red'), ylim = c(0,1),
              names.arg=bnames)
legend('topleft', cex=1,  c('Left' , 'Right'), fill=c('blue', 'red'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `names.arg` not as an argument to the `barplot` function, but as a completely separate variable- it is outside the parentheses. This:

```
plot<-barplot(tab, beside=TRUE, axisnames=FALSE, main = 'Time Spent Left vs. Right', sub = 'Female 2c', xlab= 'Days After Entry', ylab = 'Proportion of Time Spent', col=c('blue', 'red'), ylim = c(0,1))
legend('topleft', .8,  c('Left' , 'Right'), pch=c(.8), col=c('blue', 'red'))
names.arg = jd2c$d.in.p
```

should be:

```
plot<-barplot(tab, beside=TRUE, axisnames=FALSE, main = 'Time Spent Left vs. Right', sub = 'Female 2c', xlab= 'Days After Entry', ylab = 'Proportion of Time Spent', col=c('blue', 'red'), ylim = c(0,1), names.arg = jd2c$d.in.p)
legend('topleft', .8,  c('Left' , 'Right'), pch=c(.8), col=c('blue', 'red'))
```

You must also set `axisnames=TRUE` for the names to appear.

Comment: I do have have more question..        In setting up my initial plot, instead of listing values as a vector to plot, I would like to do it from the data set.. here what what I mean..   Data as vector (after rbind function):  [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]  [,6]   [,7]   [,8]
l 0.6286 0.2212 0.9961 0.5831 0.8703 0.699 0.9952 0.9948
r 0.2721 0.5663 0.0000 0.3961 0.0696 0.118 0.0000 0.0000

Comment: my data from dataset looks like this after rbind:     [,1]
 [1,] 0.2721
 [2,] 0.5663
 [3,] 0.0000
 [4,] 0.3961
 [5,] 0.0606
 [6,] 0.1180
 [7,] 0.0000
 [8,] 0.0000
 [9,] 0.6286
[10,] 0.2212
[11,] 0.9961
[12,] 0.5831
[13,] 0.8703
[14,] 0.6990
[15,] 0.9952
[16,] 0.994