# How do you label the base of each bar of a Core-Plot bar graph?

Tags: core-plot

1) How can I place a text descriptor at the base of each bar of a bar graph?
   For example, 6 months of bars, the base of each bar has their associated month names.

2) How do I adjust the gap between the bars of a bar graph?

I'm referring what was answered in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509809/labeling-in-barplot) which gives a demo, but without the documentation.  So essentially, I'm halfway there... but would like some doc to follow-up as a neophyte.

Regards,
 Ric.

Comment: The question you linked refers to the statistics package "R" but this question is tagged "core-plot", which is a Mac and iOS plotting framework. Which system are you using?

Comment: I'm working with Core-Plot.  Is there any textbook on Core-Plot?

Comment: Not that I know of. There are the [Core Plot wiki pages](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/w/list) and [API docs](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/index.html) included with the framework. You can find some tutorials on the web if you search.